# how to get magento categories and set values of categories while adding a product programatically?

Tags: magento-1.7, product, category, category-products

I want to add a product programmatically.
I have the categories like below.

```
Vehicles --
           Toyota--
                   Yaris
                   Corolla
                   Allion
           Honda--
                   Accord
                   Civic
                   Ascot
```

**How can i get the magento subcategories with above category level?**

**How can i set the subcategories while adding the product?**

i can set the category like this `->setCategoryIds(array(catid))`

**Update**

I want to get the categories in 3 level.

```
Ex. Vehicle(Main Category) - level 1

Toyota(Sub Category of Vehicle)  - level 2

Yaris(Child category of Toyota)  - level 3
```

I want to view the all subcategories(Toyota,Honda) in one Drop Down.
once i choose a subcategory i want to view the child category of selected subcategory.

Comment: question is bit unclear for me ? which category you need to add ? is product already exist or not ? please put more details

Comment: i want to get the sub categories of vehicles (both toyota and yaris) in to a select box

Comment: ok what is the relation with product and your requirement ? from where you need these subcategories, when you are in vehicle category?

Comment: actually  i want to add a vehicle(as product) in my account area,I have the main category(vehicle).While adding the vehicle i want to select the make(Toyota) and model(Yaris) to add the product programatically.

Answer (score 1):

Getting the categories can be done using the category collection:

```
$categories = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
    // .. add other filters here if necessary
    ->addPathFilter($parentCategoryId)
    ->addLevelFilter($level);
```

Setting the categories can be done like:

```
$origCategories = $product->getCategoryIds();
$product->setCategoryIds(array_merge($origCategories, $categories->getAllIds());
```